# How do I pick up trading cards?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

Steam [now has trading cards](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/).  In order to get them, you're supposed to play specific games *(currently there are [only 6 games](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq#participating_games) supported, but they've said more will come)*.

However, I can't figure out how to actually get the cards.  I played a bit of Portal 2, but didn't find any cards.

Do I need to find/pick up actual cards within the game?  Do I get them for completing certain objectives/achievements?  Do I need to beat the game?  **How do I get cards?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ah, I found my answer at the *verrry* bottom of the [Steam Trading Cards FAQ](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq#participating_games):

> Do I get Trading Cards for completing achievements in game?
>
> **Trading Card drops are currently just tied to playtime within a game, independent of which achievements you are getting.** We will definitely look into adding more rules for how cards are dropped in the future, but there are a few problems with in-game achievements that prevented us from using them right now. Many games have achievements that are grindy or un-fun to get, and we want the act of getting game cards to be fun for all users in games. We also don't want to push users to cheat or use achievement-unlockers in games in order to get cards, since that devalues achievements and isn't that fun either.

Comment: Huh, so it's entirely dependent on the time spent in the game? Like, I will start portal, get the main menu screen, go to sleep and have all the game cards the next morning :)? (Just curious, I'm not too much interested in these digital trinkets.)

Comment: @Lukas: Well, [not all of them](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq/) - you have to trade for at least half of them, [possibly more](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/117441).

Comment: @BluerRaja: Sure, I meant all the cards that you can get by "playing" the game. It's still in beta though, Steam might change it.

Answer (score 7):

To confirm, you can indeed just go to main menu and wait for +/- 20 minutes. But of course it is more fun to acually play the game.

Comment: LOL, what a challenge.

Comment: I confirm, it works.