# Can I have more than one of the same trading card?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

Steam [now has trading cards](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/).  In order to get them, you're supposed to play specific games *(currently there are [only 6 games](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq#participating_games) supported, but they've said more will come)*.

However, it's only possible to find **half** of the total trading cards for each game - you have to trade for the other half.

**Can I find the same trading card twice in the same game** *(and if so, will that count against my allowed card-pickups)*?

**Is it possible to trade for a duplicate of a card you already own?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You certainly *can* find the same card twice, or even three times! And it does, sadly, count toward your card drops.

I managed to get 3 **Wolfgang** cards from *Don't Starve*, a game that only gives you three card drops.

Also, you *can* trade for duplicate cards. I traded my *Portal 2* **Destruction** card to a friend who was then able to trade it *back* to me, despite my having a second **Destruction** card in my inventory.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can have more than one of the same trading card and trade duplicates.

There are three ways how to get trading cards:

- in-game drop
- trading
- buying them at Steam Market (prices currently range from 0.35 to 1.50 Euro per card. And you can also sell any cards you have)

For now, the quickest way to get a badge is to simply buy all cards for a game at Market. For example, TF2 has 9 cards, each costs 0.35-0.4 Euro, that's approx. 3 Euro for a badge.

BTW that seems to be the point of trading cards, to get achievement junkies to spend money on digital trinkets :).

Answer (score 2):

You can get as many trading cards as you want. You get a limited amount of drops though. Once you reach your drop limit and you want more, you can buy them from Steam Market or through trading with other players.